# Why can't I install Pygame for Python

Tags: python, pycharm, python-packaging

Why is it that every time I try to download Pygame in PyCharm using this command: `pip install pygame`, it says this:

```
pip install pygame
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Try writing in the console on Windows: python.exe -m pip install pygame

Comment: Are you sure you're running this in the terminal/shell and not in the python interactive console?

Comment: Hello! This isn't a lot of information to go on, but there are a few things you can try to narrow the problem down. First, can you include your operating system (e.g. Windows 10/11, Ubuntu, MacOS), and how you installed Python? In the meantime, there are a few things you can try: if you're on Windows, try running PowerShell, then running `python.exe -m pip install pygame` in PowerShell. If you're on Ubuntu, you can try running Terminal and running `python3 -m pip install pygame`.

Comment: If one of those commands worked, it may be that you tried to run in the Python interpreter like @Fractalism suggested, or that you ran pip with Python 2, which could also fail.

Comment: Start the "terminal" that is on one of the status bars at the bottom. In there, type your `pip install pygame` command.

Answer (score 0):

> Pygame in PyCharm

That's wrong. You're doing this in the wrong place, presumably where you're doing it is in a Pycharm `virtualenv`, you can change this, or depending on your system, open up a terminal (in Windows use Windows Command Prompt, on Mac use Terminal) and type `python -m pip install pygame`. It should download successfully.

Note that in future projects when downloading from `pip` you must use the terminal. The Python interactive console is meant for executing Python code, whereas `pip install pygame` is a shell command to download and install an external package/module, not Python code. `pip` installs must be in the terminal for them to work.

Comment: iTerm is not installed by default, nor the default terminal application for Mac. And isn't there simply a command line terminal built in to PyCharm?

Comment: I no longer use PyCharm, so I'm not sure. However, it is the convention to download modules from the Terminal, so that's why I'm doing it this way. I suspect the OP executed `pip install pygame` as actual Python code, which makes sense it ended in `SyntaxError`.

Comment: You're not reading my comment right: there is a terminal application by default on macOS, so there is no need to download and run iTerm.

Comment: And there is indeed a terminal application inside PyCharm; somewhere at the bottom, on one of the two(!) status bars.

Comment: You're right; I just found it for Mac. As for the PyCharm thing, feel free to post a separate answer, since I have no experience with PyCharm. The OP will choose which benefitted them better.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the Python Packages Manager in Pycharm through the main menu: View | Tool Windows | Python Packages. There you can install python packages through PyCharm's own UI. Just search Pygame and hit install. This will install the package on your current interpreter.

Answer (score -1):

Go to cmd and type

```
pip install pygame
```

and hit enter. It should work.

Comment: What is "cmd" ?

Comment: Command line prompt assuming you're in Windows

Comment: There is no indication the OP is using Windows.